# Can't get history.js to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, history.js

I'm hoping I can get some help with the history.js plugin. I've tried numerous examples on stackoverflow and github to try to get it working but can't for the life of me..

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. I have a list of articles with a href link for SEO purposes and a data attribute for the ajax version of the page (Is this necessary if i could use link=canonical?)
2. When I click an article a div slides up and the content is loaded into it
3. The URL is updated to "example.com/article/this-is-the-article-name" or whatever the article name happens to be, so the user can go back between articles without page reload
4. If just example.com is visited, the panel disappears as well as the content

My outputted html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/article/this-is-the-article-name" data-href="http://example.com/article/ajax/this-is-the-article-name" class="ajax-click"></a>

<div id="panel" class="hidden"></div>
```

My javascript I have attempted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var History = window.History,
State = History.getState();

// not sure if this was doing anything to prevent clicks $('.ajax-click')[0].onclick = null;
$('.ajax-click').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    History.pushState('ajax',title,path);
            if ($('#panel').hasClass('hidden')) {
          $('#panel').slideToggle(500);
          $('.header').slideToggle(600);
    }
});

// Bind to state change
// When the statechange happens, load the appropriate url via ajax
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() { // Note: Using statechange instead of popstate
load_ajax_data();
});

function load_ajax_data() {
 State = History.getState();   
 $.post(State.url, function(data) {
    $("#panel").html(data);
    });

 }
});
```

I have the jQuery library and the bundled html4 + 5 history plugin above this. I'm wondering if because I am outputting the full url and not something like "/article/article-name" it might be causing issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just part of it. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, what's the version of jQuery you are using? (As `.live` is deprecated) and also, are there any console errors?

Comment: Ended up going with Ben Cherry's PathChange instead. Only library I could get working properly. http://www.adequatelygood.com/Saner-HTML5-History-Management.html